# React-Native: Cannot trigger Native UIButton touch event

Tags: ios, swift, react-native

I am bridging a native Swift module into React Native. I created a `UIView` which creates a `UIButton` with a target handler on it. It renders everything correctly, however clicking the button does not trigger anything. I have hosted a demo here: https://github.com/esbenp/react-native-swift-test

My native module is fairly simple: https://github.com/esbenp/react-native-swift-test/blob/master/ios/TestModule.swift

```
let Button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 50))
Button.setTitleColor(UIColor.blue, for: .normal)
Button.setTitle("Press me", for: .normal)
Button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(TestModule.onClick), for: .touchUpInside)

self.addSubview(Button)
```

I bridge it using a manager: https://github.com/esbenp/react-native-swift-test/blob/master/ios/TestModuleManager.m

```
#import <React/RCTViewManager.h>
#import "ReactNativeSwiftTest-Swift.h"

@interface TestModuleManager : RCTViewManager
@end

@implementation TestModuleManager

RCT_EXPORT_MODULE()

- (UIView *)view
{
  return [[Parent alloc] init];
}

@end
```

And then run it in JS: https://github.com/esbenp/react-native-swift-test/blob/master/index.ios.js

I am no iOS expert, however it seems to be related to the frame. If I take the same native module and use it in a normal iOS project `UIViewController` like so:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    let Button = TestModule(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 500, height: 500))

    self.view.addSubview(Button)
}
```

It works. I am assuming it is because the frame that React Native creates is `width=0` and `height=0` (it says so at least if I `NSLog(String(describing: frame.size.height))`).

The [iOS MapView example](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-components-ios.html#ios-mapview-example) specifies to not override the frame as React Native will set this. I do not know if the frame is just wrong or am I missing some other context here? I tried following instructions from #2948 #15097 but nothing helps.

Answer (score 4):

I found the error here. Turns out you have to add `flex: 1` to the actual native component on the JS side to make the frame fill out properly.

**Before**

```
export default class ReactNativeSwiftTest extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Test />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

**After**

```
export default class ReactNativeSwiftTest extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Test style={{flex: 1}} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```